# Create group of users , what would be a good approach?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I built a Social Network web app in Node. I added a group model for create a group of Users like facebook.

I've been looking everywhere for a npm modules that i could use and i have searched google and stackoverflow but i haven't found anything.

This is my the Group Model I add to my proyect.

```js
var groupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    motivation: String,
    destination: String,
    days: String,
    members: [String],
    profile: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);
```

Does anyone has a good way to do this?

Note: I use a groupController and I thought to use 3 actions. One for show Users, One for add the User and One to create but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there aren't any really well rounded authorization frameworks for node yet (afaik).

I'm the author of the [express-stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/) library which does some of this, but isn't a catch-all for authorization rules yet.

The way the express-stormpath library works is like so:

- You have an Account object.
- You have a Group object.

You can create Groups, and assign Accounts to those Groups. So you might have groups called:

- admins
- users
- anonymousUsers
- etc.

Then, on each Group, you can store permission data using this JSON blob thing. So you might do something like:

Group.customData.permissions = ['can_read', 'can_write', ...];

The library also provides some middleware tools for working with users / groups, for instance, you can say something like:

```
app.get('/secret', stormpath.groupsRequired(['admins']), function(req, res) { 
  // if you get here, you must be in the admins group
});
```

If you'd like to check it out, you can read more about it here: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/

Comment: What issue did ya have? I'm happy to help. Also: you can file a github issue if you have any problems. I maintain the library and usually handle that stuff.